# find and -prune, and GNU and POSIX explanations

Tags: find

My GNU findutils (FSF 2015) says:

```
-prune
   True; 
   if the file is a directory, do not descend into it.
   If -depth is given, false; no effect.
   Because -delete implies -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together.
```

And Posix:

```
-prune
    The primary shall always evaluate as true;
    it shall cause find not to descend the current pathname if it is a directory. 
    If the -depth primary is specified, the -prune primary shall have no effect.
```

I only changed the linebreaks. Two things are remarkable:

**Are not both totally ignoring `-prune`'s main effect?** i.e. to "collect" the expressions to the left, and leave the rest to a `-o` - connected expression to the right?

With GNU's man page you at least get directed to an example:

```
-name pattern
    Base of ...
    ...
    ...   
    To ignore a directory and the files under it, use -prune;
    see an example in the description of -path.
    ...
```

Well there is a simple example  with `find . EXPR -prune -o -print`. This automatically raises the question why `find .` prints anything at all.

In retrospect, nicely laid out, it is all there.

Now the related Q:

**How are these two `-prune` explanations (GNU vs. POSIX) related?**

To me it looks like posix took a dry technical list with one useful hint and turned it into jargon prose for no reason. It is even misleading.

Because in the end both explanations leave you asking:

**Why do I need `-o` after `-prune`, if it always returns true?**

Here is a tested example: I have some mountpoints to skip, and also want to skip the ramdisk "0" (a zero), and want to list all files containing "test",

`find . -xdev -name "0" -prune -o -name '*test*'`

Like this it works; it also includes a line `./0`, which is actually interesting.

Without the prune-o-trick, I cannot make it work, even with explicit `-print`.

Comment: Note that `-prune` returning false under `-depth` was a doc error later fixed in [that commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/commit/?id=6743fefc3a1fc1386440b826b6d93500db7ca145)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas And the same commit (May 2019) rearranges that "use -prune see -path" example! Thank you for that link. Otherwise your comment is 0% helpful and besides the Q. And even if GNU is wrong, I think that hint about "usefully" combining -prune and -delete is important. Or is that part of the whole find/prune confusion?

Comment: See also [\`find\` with multiple \`-name\` and \`-exec\` executes only the last matches of \`-name\`](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/102191) which may help clear your confusion.

Comment: That link did help me indeed. I feel better now after downvoting.

Answer (score 5):

> **Are not both totally ignoring `-prune`'s main effect?** i.e. to "collect" the expressions to the left, and leave the rest to a `-o` - connected expression to the right?

No, they’re not ignoring it, because this isn’t `-prune`’s effect at all, it’s a consequence of `find`’s operator precedence.

```
find . EXPR -prune -o -print
```

is equivalent to

```
find . \( EXPR -prune \) -o -print
```

`-prune` is evaluated if `EXPR` is true. If `EXPR` is false, `-prune` isn’t evaluated, and the compound expression evaluates to false; if `EXPR` is true, since `-prune` is always true, the compound expression evaluates to true. The result of all this is that `-print` is only evaluated if `EXPR` is false, regardless of what `-prune` does.

```
find . -xdev -name "0" -prune -o -name '*test*'
```

prints `./0` as well as the various `*test*` matches because of the following rule (quoting the manpage):

> If the whole expression contains no actions other than `-prune` or `-print`, `-print` is performed on all files  for
>          which the whole expression is true.

On `0`, `-name "0" -prune` evaluates to true, so it is printed.

This rule also explains why `find .` behaves as it does.

The GNU and POSIX explanations are equivalent:

- “True; ” matches “The primary shall always evaluate as true;”
- “if the file is a directory, do not descend into it.” matches “it shall cause find not to descend the current pathname if it is a directory.”
- “If -depth is given, then -prune has no effect.” matches “If the -depth primary is specified, the -prune primary shall have no effect.”

(quoting [the amended `find` documentation](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/commit/?id=6743fefc3a1fc1386440b826b6d93500db7ca145)).

`-prune` doesn’t have to be followed by `-o`, and there are a few examples which illustrate that in [the POSIX documentation for `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html). This trick in particular is useful to limit `find` to the immediate contents of the current directory:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -print
```

Comment: "it's not an effect, it's a consequence" I take this for a "yes". And: exactly because of this "equivalence" I want to know if they share a common source. I was not asking how find works, but what makes -prune a bit special, besides the boolean expression-action language per se, and if not both GNU and POSIX could use a few extra lines to clarify. (Even if it can never be as clear as you explain all this.)

Comment: You’re missing the objects of the effect and consequence. Asking “Are not both totally ignoring `-prune`'s main effect?”, with your definition of “`-prune`’s main effect”, is similar to asking “Are not both totally ignoring that cows have wings?” You should take my answer for a “no”, because there is nothing to ignore: cows don’t have wings, and `-prune`’s main effect isn’t what you’re describing.

Comment: @rastafile, you can do something similar with `-o` even without touching `-prune`. Say something like running different commands for files and for directories: `find . -type f -exec echo file: {} \; -o -type d -exec echo dir: {} \;`