# Exclude hidden directory from find and delete

Tags: shell-script, find

I am working on a purging logic where i need to delete the logs older than 7 days.

Now the logs are of two types :
1) begins with developer_ and 
2) ends with _c

The logs I am concerned about are only after `/NAS/logs` and not after any other subfolders in this path.

below are logs sample:

```
/NAS/logs/.snapshot/Enterprise_Primary.2019-11-17_1300/developer_score_20191113.log
/NAS/logs/.snapshot/Enterprise_Primary.2019-11-17_1300/trdcvf_03_00_c.log.20191113163858
/NAS/logs/trddffgc004_00_c.log.20191118030038
/NAS/logs/developer_run_score.log.20191118030039
```

Here I want to exclude all the logs which are in the hidden folder .snapshot as i dont have access on those.

I am trying to identify them using below command but it keeps giving me the .snapshot files as well.

I also tried -prune option but no help.

```
  find /NAS/logs/  -mindepth 1 -type f  \( -iname "*_c.log.*" -or -iname "developer_run_*"  \) -not -path "./.snapshot/*"
```

Final command

```
find /NAS/logs/  -mindepth 1 -type f  \( -iname "*_c.log.*" -or -iname "developer_run_*"  \) -not -path "./.snapshot/*"-mtime +7 -delete
```

Can anyone please help me to exclude that directory from the find?

Comment: Got the answer-- I was using mindepth 1 instead of maxdepth 1

Comment: None of your files matches your criterion 2 "_ends with `_c`_". Did you mean "_contains `_c`_" perhaps? But even then you have no files matching criterion 1 _and_ criterion 2. Perhaps that was also intended to be _or_?

Comment: **EXPR -prune -o ...** this reminds me of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549274/find-and-prune-and-gnu-and-posix-explanations. (-prune can be important for performance reasons, nomen est omen, try `-D tree` debug option.

Comment: @roaima, sorry for the confusion ..i meant to say *_c.log.*. Also, I was able to get the desired by using the maxdepth 1 option. is that fine?

Comment: If you have solved your own problem please post your own answer. I don't understand why you'd want `-maxdepth` anywhere, though.

Comment: I would want maxdepth to restrict find into searching in the subfolders as the logs i am concerned about is only after /NAS/logs/ and not after any other subfolders in this path.

Comment: In that case the solution is far simpler. I'll update my answer now that you've provided more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your example files satifies the second of the filename criteria you have specified. There are files containing `_c` but none ends with `_c`. Assuming you meant *contains* you can construct the `find` command like this:

```
find /NAS/logs -type d -path '/NAS/logs/.snapshot' -prune -o -type f -mtime +7 \( -name 'developer_*' -o -name '*_c*' \) -print
```

This can be broken down into two parts (the `-o` (or) condition):

1. The tree path matching `/NAS/logs/.snapshot` is discarded (pruned) and no further action is considered there.
2. Files modified more than seven days ago, with a name matching either `developer_*` or `*_c*`, are listed (printed).

You should replace `-print` with `-delete`, or simply append `-delete` to remove the files you've matched.

If you want to prune any instance of the directory `.snapshot` you could modify the first part of the matching criteria like this

```
find /NAS/logs -type d -name '.snapshot' -prune -o ...
```

---

Now that you have added extra information to your question, none of the pruning complexity is actually required any more. You can just use this:

```
find /NAS/logs -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +7 \( -name 'developer_*' -o -name '*_c*' \) -print
```

(This shows the importance of providing full information in your question rather than delivering it piecemeal - or not at all.)

Comment: Thanks @Roaima will make sure i put all the information going forward.

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried -prune option but no help

And what happened?

The link in my comment shows there is a problem with -prune and -delete together, because of -depth. [find-and-prune-explanations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549274/find-and-prune-and-gnu-and-posix-explanations)

I think here you have to do something like

`... -path '*/.snapshot/*' -o ... ... -delete`

Only with massive data (and tests) you would miss the '-prune' action.

---

`find kernel -path '*/sched/*' -o -name '???.c' -exec grep -H 'struct ta' {} +`

finds lines in sys.c, pid.c and cpu.c.

The same without the `-o` (same as with `-a`) gives three lines in kernel/sched/psi.c only.